# libc6-dbg depends on older version of libc6. Is there way to downgrade?

Tags: raspberry-pi, downgrade

I'm getting this error that libc6 depends on an older version. Is there a way to downgrade this?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u2) but 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u3 is to be installed
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

`1. $ sudo apt remove libc6-dbg -y`

`2. $sudo apt update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

If you are sure need install libc6-dbg, please execute below

`$ sudo apt install libc6-dbg`